# What is the name or how else would I describe these function union and intersection operators?

Tags: functions

Consider a 3 functions f, g, h, i.
I would like to compose f and g in two different ways such that their domains and ranges are combined using union and intersection.

f: {a,b} -> {c,d}

g: {b,c} -> {d,e}

So

h = f union g

i = f intersect g

h: {a,b,c} -> {c,d,e}

i: {b} -> {d}

What would be the name of these operators or what is the best way of describing them?

Comment: I can’t tell what you really mean, but the first is probably a piecewise definition and the second a restriction.

Comment: How do you define $f \cup g$ if $f(b) \neq g(b)$?

Comment: it does not depend on whether or not f(b) = g(b), I haven't referred to the actual mappings, just the signature

Comment: It matters because if $f(b) \neq g(b)$ then $f\cup g$ will not be a function. You could define $f \cup g$ as a relation, though. What do you mean by $f \cup g$?

Comment: ok sure then yes f union g and f intersect g must both be total functions